# How to see object generation in netbeans profiler 8.2

Tags: netbeans, profiler

[Netbeans profiler documentation](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ProfilerObjects) says one can track only live objects and see object generations. However I don't find how to select to view only live objects, so I obtain a view with only the columns live object and live bytes.

Where can I select to view only live objects? The "console" I have is the one shown in the image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: one must click on the down arrow on the line where "live objects" and "live bytes" are, then select some classes, and then "Track only live objects" will appear, giving the possibility to show objects generations from the same down arrow as before

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

The following may be same as you describe, but to be clearer:

1. Click on the "settings" gear icon right
2. Go to the label *Profile:* on the left and click on the pulldown menu right of that label (which has a small down arrow) and choose 'Selected classes' under **Focused (instrumented)**.
3. Click on the link that enables you to edit which classes are selected, and add some classes (and Apply).

The 'Track only live objects' option appears.

BTW: The NetBeans Profile docs do not make it clear what the difference is between "live" and "allocated" objects, and the column behaviour is a bit confusing.

To get the columns to reflect the live objects option/choice, even after Apply, you have to load something that populates the columns 'Live Objects' and 'Allocated Objects'. Sometimes, depending on the heap, you can see one or the other of those columns, but not both.

---

EDIT: Aha, it depends on the OS, too. From http://wiki.netbeans.org/ProfilerObjects

> Tip: The columns can be displayed or hidden using the right corner
>   button in the view header by clicking the dropdown arrow (or right
>   clicking the header on Mac OS X).